# Kubernetes config file from host to container?

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting an error mounting a config file, can anyone assist?

With subPath on volumeMounts I get the error:

```
Error: stat /var/config/openhim-console.json: no such file or directory.
```

I can read this file.

Without subPath on volumeMounts I get this error:

```
Warning  Failed   13s                kubelet, ip-10-0-65-230.eu-central-1.compute.internal  Error: failed to start container "openhim-console": Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/var/config/openhim-console.json\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7408e2aa7e93b3c42ca4c2320681f61ae4bd4b02208364eee8da5f51d587ed21/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7408e2aa7e93b3c42ca4c2320681f61ae4bd4b02208364eee8da5f51d587ed21/merged/usr/share/nginx/html/config/default.json\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
  Warning  BackOff  2s  kubelet, ip-10-0-65-230.eu-central-1.compute.internal  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Here is the deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: openhim-console-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: openhim-console
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: openhim-console
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: console-config
          hostPath:
            path: /var/config/openhim-console.json
      containers:
        - name: openhim-console
          image: jembi/openhim-console:1.13.rc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: console-config
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/config/default.json
              subPath: default.json
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
```

Comment: Probably hostPath should hold a path rather than your file `path: /var/config/openhim-console.json` as you're mounting a volume, not a file. If so, the type should be specified as `File`, see [docs#hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)

Comment: Thanks @Webber appreciate your help. I did try the File type before but it did not work. BUT just mapping the folder and not the file worked. Really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @SureshVishnoi did not try File again, I tried before but it failed.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `hostPath` should hold a `path` rather than your file path: `/var/config/openhim-console.json` as you're mounting a volume, not a file.

If you are, the `type` should be specified as `File`.

See also [docs#hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)

Comment: Hi Webber,

I have another very strange thing with this topic. I am able for this to work 100% using Minikube and Virtualbox to a shared volume but I am having an impossible time on Linux.

Do you know if there are any special permissions needed for the files to be visible? I have run this on the directory I use /var/config/openhim-console

sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/config but still I am unable to see these files from the container?

Comment: Hi @AntonSwanevelder, while the issue may be on the same topic, you're still asking a different question. You're now also not asking the community but me personally. In order to also help other people that have the same question, i think it's best if you post a new question for this new issue. You can always link to the other question in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Webber, I took a chance. Here is the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406963/kubernetes-volumemount-folder-and-file-permissions?noredirect=1#comment97549073_55406963

Answer (score 0):

You should either use:

```
  volumes:
  - name: host-file
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/waagent.log
      type: File
```

or

```
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /data
      # Directory is the default, so this field is optional. 
      type: Directory
```

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
    - mountPath: /var/log/lala/aaa.log
      name: host-file
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
  - name: host-file
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/waagent.log
      type: File
```

[subpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) is generally used when you need to mount only one path inside the container instead of the root.

You can find more details in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).