# Kubernetes volumeMount folder and file permissions?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Trying to mount config files from a hostPath to a kubernetes container. This works using minikube and VirtualBox shared folder, but I am unable to make this work on Linux.

I making use of AWS EKS and the following architecture https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/amazon-eks/. I think my problem is that the files need to live on each of the EKS Node instances.

Here is the architecture diagram:
[image]

Below is the Deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: openhim-core-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: openhim-core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: openhim-core
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: core-config
          hostPath:
            path: /var/config/openhim-core
      containers:
        - name: openhim-core
          image: jembi/openhim-core:5.rc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 5000
            - containerPort: 5001
          volumeMounts:
            - name: core-config
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/config
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
```

Comment: can you please add output of  `kubectl logs pod_name` and result of `ls -l /var/config/openhim-core`?

Comment: Thanks in advance. I've added the outputs. I ran chmod 777 -R /var/config/

Comment: Think my issue is due to the multi-availability zones of AWS EKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pain I found that I am trying to place the configuration on the Linux Bastion host where I have access to kubectl but in fact this configuration will have to be on each of the EC2 instances in every availability zone.

The solution for me was to make use of a initContainer.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: openhim-core-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: openhim-core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: openhim-core
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: core-config
          hostPath:
            path: /var/config/openhim-core
      containers:
        - name: openhim-core
          image: jembi/openhim-core:5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 5000
            - containerPort: 5001
          volumeMounts:
            - name: core-config
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/config
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
      initContainers:
        - name: install
          image: busybox
          command:
          - wget
          - "-O"
          - "/usr/src/app/config/development.json"
          - https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/../development.json
          volumeMounts:
            - name: core-config
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/config"      
      volumes:
        - name: core-config
          emptyDir: {}
```